# anchor deploy: Invalid Blockhash

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rpc, devnet, deploy

I've been trying to deploy an Anchor program on `devnet` but it seems to be stuck in the process, and then gives the following error after a while,

```
$ anchor deploy --provider.cluster d

Error: Custom: Invalid blockhash
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

Seems like its timing out, and could be `devnet` issue but the Explorer seems to show that `devnet` is working fine. I'm also able to deploy locally easily on `solana-test-validator`, so it shouldn't be an issue with the program itself right?

Comment: Very often it's the node (invalid blockhash) and you just need one that's not lagging  https://solana.com/rpc

Answer (score 2):

Devnet acts that way sometimes. Sometimes there's too many requests and if your network connection isn't fast enough it times out. I just use solana playground to deploy to devnet now. It's more convenient. https://beta.solpg.io.

1. Import your solana cli wallet from `keypair.json` on your local environment. The playground wallet is located on the top right.
2. Click on the 2nd icon on the top left and import your program keypair and .so file from the `/target/deploy` folder.
3. Deploy.

Answer (score 1):

In your project's root directory, there is an `Anchor.toml` file.

Within that file, there is a `[provider]` section.

```
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"
```

The `cluster = "xyz"` line needs to point to the same cluster that you are trying to deploy to.

There are four possible values: `localnet`, `devnet`, `testnet` and `mainnet`.

So when trying to deploy to `devnet`, make sure you have `cluster = "devnet"` in the `[provider]` section of your `Anchor.toml`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Anchor and Solana CLI.

For Solana:

> sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.32/install)"

For Anchor:

> cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --locked --force

Update your Anchor.toml file accordingly with the new versions.

Comment: I updated them, but I'm not sure what you meant to update in `Anchor.toml`. I tried deploying again after updating the CLIs, but still same issue.

Comment: The Anchor.toml is in your project folder (together with folders named ‘program’, ‘test’, etcetera. In this Anchor.toml file you need to change the versions to the version of Anchor and Solana that you just updated.

Answer (score -1):

Use a custom `RPC` , such as `https://devnet.genesysgo.net` the default public ones aren't suitable for that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: Need to put it in `cluster="https://devnet.genesysgo.net"` inside `Anchor.toml`.